# linux top memory utlilization - RES column

Tags: linux, memory, huge-pages

We are having a java process with 2g Heap size. But top command "RES" Column displays only 143m. Later on we found that, we are allocating, 2.5g of hugepage size with the following command. If we remove this command for hugepage creation, then "RES" column shows correctly as 2.3g.

```
echo 1280 > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepage
```

So from this, we can conclude that when hugepage allocated, hugepage area of the memory allocation doesn't get displayed in "RES" column of top output.

Can anyone answer my questions -

1. Is there any other linux command from where we can find out the memory allocation from the hugepage area of the process?

I used `/proc/<pid>/smaps` as well as `pmap -X <pid>`. But not able to find it.

2. top command "RES" 143m -> what does it mean? Is the pagetable size or memory allocation of the process outside the hugepage area.